# Problemas para importar base de datos MySQL a WorkBench y PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Estoy tratando de importar una base de datos `MySQL`, tanto por medio de **WorkBench**, como de **PHPMyAdmin**, todo se ejecuta de manera correcta, pero no importa absolutamente nada.

**Importado en WorkBench**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Importado PHPMyAdmin**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Los mensajes en rojo no son importantes, siempre me han funcionado las importaciones aunque aparezca ese mensaje.

Answer (score 1):

-Hace unos días tuve problemas similares con MySQL versión 8.0 (Aun esta versión es inestable).

-Te recomiendo que la desintales e intentes con la versión 5.7 y me dices que tal te fue ;)

-En mi caso instale WampServer...

Peor de los casos, actualiza el usuario root, ejecutando este comando en la shell.

```
mysql> use mysql;
​mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('ingresapassword') where user='root';
​mysql> flush privileges;
​mysql> quit
```

Comment: Esto es un comentario y debería ir en la sección de comentarios no en la de respuestas ;)